# Why do my objects become transparent instead of being removed with UPBGE?

Tags: python, scripting

I add an object using `addObject()`, but when I put a time to be alive, when the time ends, the object does not delete, it becomes transparent. See:

[image]

Why?

Script:

```
from bge import *
from mathutils import *
from random import randint

class Component(types.KX_PythonComponent):

  args = {
    "speed" : 0.1
  }

  def start(self, args):
    self.speed = args["speed"]   
    
    scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
    
    empty = scene.objects["Empty"]
    
    for object in range(11):
        torus = scene.addObject("Suzanne", empty, 33.0)    
        
        torus.worldPosition = [randint(-20, 20), randint(-20, 20), 1]
        
  def update(self):
    pass
```

I am using UPBGE 0.3.0.
[I speak portuguese, sorry for english mistakes]